# JavaScript: How to define an "object"

Tags: javascript

I'm using the very handy **[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)** tool to ensure my javascript is strict.

I have the following code that is being flagged by JSLint:

```
var my_obj = new Object();   // <-- JSLint states "Use the object literal notation {}."
var numKP = 1;

while (query.indexOf('&') > -1) {
    keypairs[numKP] = query.substring(0,query.indexOf('&'));
    query = query.substring((query.indexOf('&')) + 1);
    numKP++;
}

keypairs[numKP] = query;

for (i in keypairs) {
    my_obj[keypairs] = keypairs[i];
}
```

How should I fix the code above to make it JavaScript "strict" (pass the JSLint validator)?

Answer (score 4):

Literally as the message says, in fact:

```
var my_obj = {};
```

This defines an object that has no explicit properties, which is equivalent to what you were doing but better from JSLint's perspective.  (<s>I believe this is because it doesn't explicitly invoke a constructor,  but to be honest I don't really know</s> Edit: according to the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) section 11.1.5 it's entirely equivalent to `new Object()`.  I guess it's cool because it's shorter and less prone to typos.)

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
 var my_obj = {};
```

{} is javascript notation to create an object literal.